# VS Code Jest and Cypress intellisense doesn't work properly with Chai

Tags: visual-studio-code, jestjs, intellisense, cypress

I am using Jest as unit testing framework and bellow intellisense is correct:

[image]

However, when I install Cypress `"cypress": "^3.2.0"`, the same code now displaying error `Property 'toMatch' does not exist on type 'Assertion'. Did you mean 'match'?`. The reason for that IMO is Cypress install typings under `node_modules/cypress/types/chai/index.d.ts` and VS Code is picking them for intellisense. Both Jest and Cypress have dependency on Chai assertion library. Intellisense after installing Cypress:

[image]

Is there a way to tell VS Code which Chai intellisense to use in specific folder? Or is there some way to specify it in `jsconfig.json` file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution was to create aliases for those global variables exposed in [Jest](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/api)
and decorate those variables with `@type` in JSDoc. So, I created a file `jestGlobals.js` in same directory where my tests are.

`jestGlobals.js` file: (I included only one global for sake of simplicity, but you would do the same thing for all global variables):

```
/** @type {jest.Expect} */
// @ts-ignore
let expect = global.expect

export { expect }
```

Then I just import those variables in my `*.spec.js` files:

```
import { expect } from './jestGlobals'
```

Now, when I use this aliases, I got correct intellisense like this:
[image]

Answer (score 9):

Had the same problem with cypress and jest.

I solved it by creating two jsconfig.json

cypress/jsconfig.json

```
{
  "typeAcquisition": { "include": ["cypress"] }
}
```

and then one for my src folder

src/jsconfig.json

```
{
  "typeAcquisition": { "include": ["jest"] }
}
```

Restarted VSCode and it worked as expected

Comment: This is the only solution working for me.

Answer (score 8):

Facing this issue myself too.

Usually I can type the assertions by heart, but when you really need autocompletion, adding

```js
/// <reference types="jest" />
```

(A [triple-slash directive](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/triple-slash-directives.html#-reference-types-)) On the top of your test suite file will give you the correct jest types.

Note: you need to have [`@types/jest`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/jest) installed too!

[image: VS Code dialog with proper type reference]

Comment: I'm going to edit the comment. You need to have `@types/jest` installed too!

Answer (score 0):

Found this answer on GitHub https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/22059#issuecomment-1148921141

Adding `./cypress.config.ts` to `exclude` in my tsconfig.json worked for me